# How to replace a new line with a '\n' in bash

Tags: bash

In bash have the following variable:

```
test="test
text"
```

which I would like to transform in a string with `\n`.

```
test="test\ntext"
```

Could not find how to do that. This has to work across multiple flavors of unix (linux, darwin, etc.) so `sed` is probably not an option as I now it works differently on linux and darwin.

Thanks for any suggestion.

## Update

As @oguz ismail pointed out in the comments, the answer is:

```
echo "${varWithNewlines//$'\n'/\\n}"
```

with `//` to make sur all new lines are converted.

Comment: See [this answer](/a/23848322/10248678).

Answer (score 1):

With GNU bash and its [Parameter Expansion](http://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion):

```
test="${test/$'\n'/\\n}"
```